# Android Studio Can Not Find My Device - Lenovo Yoga

Tags: android, connection, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, tablet

I have a problem connecting my Lenovo Yoga tablet with Android Studio. I am using AS 1.5 and the Yoga is with 4.2.2 Android. My Machine is using Windows 10 the latest iteration. So on the problem, I made completely new and blank project trying to run it on the device in order to make sure everything is conneceted right before start the project. When i press run AS only finds the emulator and not the Yoga device. My friend is able to run the same exact project with the same configs at her computer, but I can't. Please assist. If you need any further information I'll provide it.

Comment: Have you installed adb driver for Lenovo yoga? http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds022366

Comment: Yes, I did installed the driver. Windows finds the device and is able to work with it, but Android - not.

Comment: Solution can be kill ADB process and restart android studio.Open Android studio monitor and check the status of the device also make sure your minSDKVersion should be less than SDK 16

Comment: There is a difference between the `Device Driver` and the `ADB interface driver`. Go to your `Device manager` and check if you have the `ADB interface` for the device that you are talking about.

Answer (score 7):

You can download your ADB driver from here : 
http://androidmtk.com/download-lenovo-usb-drivers

install that and android studio will find your device.

That works for me

Comment: Worked for my Lenovo Tab 2 A10-70F

Comment: Found here drivers of Lenovo TB3-730. Thanks!